# Panaroma software for ubuntu?

Tags: photo-editing

Software for stitching photos together for panaroma view in Ubuntu ?
Any link where I can get proper installation guide ? I use GIMP and picasa.
Picasa doesnot seem to have much control in stitching photos , (may be thru collage) ,

Gimp has something called Pandora which dint work !! or say I dint understand !! If someone is using GIMP for Panaroma , I would like to know how to use it properly.

then read about Hugin , dint get proper links(or guides) to install it !!

Comment: at first I read this question as "Paranormal software for Ubuntu". No offense but I think that versions is even MORE interesting :)

Comment: @BBischof -- Did u watch Paranormal activity recently ?!! :)

Comment: No actually, I don't know why I thought that hehe

Comment: Does this question belong here or at askubuntu?

Comment: @AIB -- When I asked this question askubuntu was not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support John's answer. Run Synaptic Package Manager and in the quick search field type Hugin. Select the packages shown and hit Apply. Hugin will be downloaded and installed. It couldn't be easier.

Hugin is a very capable program for creating panoramas. So good in fact that it is indistinguishable from magic!

Comment: Hugin got installed easily , no problems what so ever. Asking in this forum is better than searching endlessly in Google.

Comment: Great, ask again if you need help using it.

Answer (score 12):

Hugin is available in the [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/hugin) so you should be able to install it as you would any Ubuntu package (depending on the version of Ubuntu you're using). It's available in 9.04 and up as a minimum. The link I provided is for the latest and includes a link to the Hugin development site which has tutorials and guides on usage. Good luck.

Comment: [Hugin tutorials](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/index.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial , Installed Hugin and created a panaroma too with it , If program can calculate control points , It works like a charm . ( no need to even see the tutorial ! ) Hats off to programmers of this Software !!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of software for stitching panoramas: those that are easy and those that are not.

The easiest and free ones are only available for Windows so far. The way I manage is to to run them in a Windows 7 VM under OpenSUSE, [AutoStitch](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) works flawlessly that way. There is a paid Linux software using the same algorithms, its called [AutoPano](http://www.autopano.net/en).

You can use other software like Hugin but they are complex enough to turn most people off from doing panoramas. I have seen awesome results though from people who obviously got over the learning curve.